# Box2D in xcode generating linker errors

Tags: xcode, linker, box2d, linker-errors

I have added Box2D to my existing XCode 4.3.1 project... I set the 'Header Search Path' setting and the compiler is not having troubles finding the headers... the problem comes when the linker looks for definitions... I am using a really basic code to just create a b2world and set some parameters. But the linker is complaining because it couldn't find any compiled definitions of the methods I use... so this means that XCode is not compiling Box2D. How can I solve?? I already tried to set all the .cpp files properties to 'ObjectiveC++ source file' but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add box2d to the scheme you're running.  Product->edit scheme, then on the left click build and see if box2d is listed in the build targets and if it is listed before you build your app.  If not, add it with the plus and see if that works.